# OpenCart - Can't update admin dashboard

Tags: php, webserver, web

I can't update my admin dashboard for some reason. I want to add a feature to search by phone number but no updates are occuring. I'm changing:

- admin/view/template/sale/order_form.twig
- admin/controller/customer/customer.php (autocomplete)
- admin/model/customer/customer.php (getCustomers)

I also tried removing and re-adding cache as well as refreshing in the admin dashboard, and removing the cache manually in /system/storage/cache, to no avail. Can someone help?

Comment: If you use OC version 3.x.x.x in admin dashboard you must: refresh modifications, and clear cache...  blue icon in right upper angle (in admin dashboard). And clear your browser cache. Should work if your modification are correct.

Comment: I have tried pressing the refresh button and disabling and re-enabling cache, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Did you refresh in your admin dashboard, Extensions/Modifications and button refresh?

Comment: Yes I pressed the refresh in the admin dashboard. Idk what you mean about extensions and modifications tho - I'm editing the files directly.

Comment: Even if you edit directly, some files can be used of some modifications using OCMOD.... I don't know that. So for that, you must refresh your modifications.